# show $\frac{n}{d}$ is the additive order

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $n>1$ and $a>0$ are integers and $d=gcd(a,n)$ then the additive order of $a\pmod{n}$ is $\frac{n}{d}$. 
 *Additive order is the smallest positive integer that satisfies $ax\equiv 0\pmod{n}$

> This is what I have so far. Suppose $n>1$ and $a>0$ where $a,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $d=gcd(a,n)\implies d|a$ and $d|n$. First we want to show that $\frac{n}{d}$ is a solution to $ax\equiv 0\pmod{n}$. First observe that $\frac{n}{d}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $x=\frac{n}{d}$ and we get $\frac{an}{d}\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ Since $d|a$ we get that $\frac{n}{d}$ is a solution. Next we show that $\frac{n}{d}$ is the additive order of $a\pmod{n}$. Suppose not that $e$ is the additive order of $a\pmod{n}$ and $e<\frac{n}{d}$ That is $ae\equiv 0\pmod{n}\implies n|ae$. Since $n|ae$ it follows that $n|de\implies nt=de$ for some $t\in\mathbb{Z}\implies \frac{nt}{d}=e\implies \frac{n}{d}|e$. Thus $e\equiv 0\pmod{\frac{n}{d}}$. Since $e<\frac{n}{d}$ and $e>0$ this means $e=\frac{n}{d}$ hence a contradiction.

Comment: You should explain why from $n\mid ae$ we can conclude that $n\mid de$.

Comment: oh it follows from the fact that if $n|ae$ then $n|gcd(a,n)*e$.

Comment: is the rest of the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, or more crudely let $a=da'$, $n=dn'$. Then $a'$ and $n'$ are relatively prime.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll do that instead.

Comment: Looks fine, there is a small typo in the second line, you have $b$ where you mean $n$.